# Merge values of two fields into one across a collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there any way to merge values of two fields into one field or array?
I have a MongoDB collection like this:

```
{"_id": 1, "side1": "a", "side2": "b"},
{"_id": 2, "side1": "c", "side2": "b"},
{"_id": 3, "side1": "b", "side2": "d"},
{"_id": 4, "side1": "a", "side2": "d"}
```

How to get an array containing all values of side1 and side2.

```
{"_id": null, "sides": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]}
```

The id isn't important. I have tried many aggregations and cascading query commands and just can't come up with desired response.

Comment: It is not possible to have multiple records with same _id. Please post the correct data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'v just find a simpler solution:

```
   db.LINK.aggregate([
     { $group: {"_id":0,"list1":{$addToSet:"$side1"},"list2":{$addToSet:"$side2"}}} ,
     { $project: {array:{$setUnion:["$list1","$list2"]}}}
   ])
```